# How to create a horizontal form in Phalcon

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment, phalcon

A very basic question. I studied the examples & tutorials like INVO & Vokuro provided by Phalcon. The Vokuro example uses forms but all the examples use vertical forms (one field below other). They use forms.render() function using volt template and the form itself. If I want to create Phalcon form with fields arranged in two or more columns, how do I do it. Is the only way to use html tables or is there some other way.

Here is code from Vokuro "Users form" example which creates a vertical form:

```
<div class="clearfix">  <label for="name">Name</label>
    {{ form.render("name") }}
</div>

<div class="clearfix">  <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
    {{ form.render("email") }}
</div>

<div class="clearfix">  <label for="profilesId">Profile</label>
    {{ form.render("profilesId") }}
</div>
```

And corresponding form code is:

```
$name = new Text('name', array('placeholder' => 'Name' ));
$name->addValidators(array(
    new PresenceOf(array('message' => 'The name is required'
    ))    ));
$this->add($name);

$email = new Text('email', array('placeholder' => 'Email'    ));
$email->addValidators(array(
    new PresenceOf(array('message' => 'The e-mail is required' )),
    new Email(array( 'message' => 'The e-mail is not valid'
    ))    ));
$this->add($email);

$this->add(new Select('profilesId', Profiles::find('active = "Y"'), array(
    'using' => array('id', 'name' ),.....some more code.......)));
```

This creates a form as given below:

> **Create a User**
>
> Name
>
> [Text Box]
>
> E-Mail
>
> [Text Box]
>
> Profile
>
> [List Box]

If I try to use style="float:left" in the div tags, it doesn't help much neither removing them. I want a form like:

label: [input field]   -gap-   label: [input field]

label: [input field]   -gap-   label: [input field]

If space permits, create three columns instead of two as shown above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is because they have every element in a separate div

```
<div class="clearfix">  <label for="name">Name</label>
    {{ form.render("name") }}
</div>

<div class="clearfix">  <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
    {{ form.render("email") }}
</div>
```

But you can arrange that any way you want. For example in one row:

```
<div class="clearfix">  
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    {{ form.render("name") }}
    <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
    {{ form.render("email") }}
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't work. It clubbed all the label fields together on the left and all the input text fields to their right. It was not like "label - inputbox    label - inputbox" kind of layout and there was no gap between any of the labels or boxes.

Answer (score 0):

use it

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">Name</label>
      {{ form.render("name",['class': 'form-control']) }}
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      {{form.render("email",['class': 'form-control'])}}
</div>
```